# Do I need to transfer Server license CALs to new Domain Controller during AD transition?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have an old Server 2003 domain controller I'm ready to decommission.  I notice in Server 2003 there is a Licensing module under Administrative Tools that seems to manage and track user CAL's for the domain controller. I don't see this on my newly promoted Server 2008 domain controller, nor do I see any roles to add it.  Does this need to be transferred to my new Server 2008 domain controller or will it all happen when the old server is decommissioned?

I've already transferred all my Terminal Server licenses to the new server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2008, you just need to be sure you have enough CALs for your usage, there is no console as in 2003.  This is different from RDS/TS licenses which are managed by the Remote Desktop License server.

You can mix per user and per device CALs in 2008, but it's probably easier to manage a single licensing model.

You should be aware that CALs are version specific - if you are upgrading from 2003 to 2008, you either need to be covered under software assurance, or you need to buy new CALs.  Since you commented that you have the 2008 CALs, that's all you need.  (As long as you have R2 CALs if you're going with R2.)

[2008 R2 Server Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx) covers most of this.

Comment: I bought the CAL's last year. They are server 2008 CAL's that are backwards compatible with 2003 server.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (I think it might have been in the SQL licensing documents, but it applies globally) that apart from TS, MS have done away with all internal tracking of CALs, so when you purchase CALs the invoice is all you need to prove your right to the licenses, hence why that console is no longer present in 2k8

Comment: I can't actually find an official document on the MS web site, but it's easy to find semi-official statements that you just need to _have_ enough and the right type of CALs, there's no license manager to _enforce_ having them.

Comment: There was no enforcement in W2k3 either except for TS and SBS.

Comment: Indeed. But to compensate, the SBS CALs actually covered all the other servers inside the SBS domain. Also, in a 2008/2011 server environment, you now need to have dedicated CALs for your SQL users/seats.